# MDX Request : How to Topcount without specific members

Tags: mdx, olap

I'm new to MDX and i am having troubles with the TOPCOUNT() function.

*Lets say i want the following result →*

[image]

*This is what I get →*
[image: Img02]

*Here is like what my request would look like with this exemple →*

WITH

SET **SpecificStores** AS EXCEPT([Stores].CHILDREN,[Stores].&[Store3])

SET TopProducts AS TOPCOUNT(SpecificStores * [Products],3,[Measures].[QTE])

SELECT {[Measures].[QTE]} ON COLUMNS,

{TopProducts} ON ROWS

FROM [MyCube];

The **SpecificStores** Member seems to work like a list and not like a unique member, is there a way to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your SpecificStores as a set: a list of all children (except the one you're excluding). The TopProducts set will be calculated based on that.

What you want is to define SpecificStores as a member:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Stores].[SpecificStores] AS Aggregate( EXCEPT([Stores].CHILDREN,[Stores].&[Store3]) )
  SET TopProducts as TopCount( {[Stores].[SpecificStores]} * [Products].Children , 3, [Measures].[QTE])
SELECT
  TopProducts on Rows,
  [Measures].[QTE] on Columns
FROM [MyCube]
```